# ¿Podría traducirse la fecha en el título del boletín que se envía por email?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, traducciones, agregar-a-transifex

Cada miércoles Stack Overflow en español envía [un boletín](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters), a quien lo quiera, con tres secciones:

- Preguntas principales de esta semana:
- Grandes éxitos de semanas anteriores.
- ¿Puedes responder estas preguntas?

Todo el contenido está en castellano pero la fecha del título no. Por ejemplo el de hoy dice:

> Boletín de Stack Overflow en español - Wednesday, December 19, 2018

Busco en traducir.win y no aparece esta cadena. Bueno, sí sale el *Wednesday* pero ya está traducido.

¿Podría incluirse en Transifex para que así podamos traducirlo?

Comment: Relacionado : [Newsletter localization issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313464/289691)

Comment: tenés idea de algún lugar donde se muestre la fecha bien en el sitio?

Comment: @g3rv4 no me consta haber visto ningún _miércoles_ en el sitio. ¿Lo mismo en la cajetilla lateral de "destacado en Meta" cuando se crea un evento?

Comment: :thumbsup: ya encontré una forma y mandé un PR... aviso cuando esté mergeado (va a aparecer como "miércoles, 19 de diciembre de 2018", que es [el formato D en ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listo! ya quedó traducida la fecha y traducible "asked by" y "answered by".

Para que esos textos salgan traducidos en los mails, hay que traducir las siguientes cadenas:

- [asked by $user$](https://traducir.win/string/12726)
- [answered by $user](https://traducir.win/string/12728)

La fecha no es necesario traducirla porque cambié el texto a [`DateTime.ToString("D")`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Comment: Fantástico, mil gracias! Ya propuse traducción. Lo de "D" entiendo que usa el locale definido, pero no sé cuál será el formato.

Comment: @fedorqui exacto, en español aparece como "miércoles, 01 de octubre de 2008" (y la razón por la que fui por eso, es porque el orden del día, mes y año cambia en los distintos idiomas)

Comment: Ya se ve perfecto, tanto la fecha como lo de "formulada" y "respondida" --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/kox9f.png

Comment: \o/ success \o/